# vim highlighting doesn't set the right type for a new filetype

Tags: linux, syntax-highlighting

This is what I have in my `/usr/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim` (the only mention of `messages` in the file) :

```
" Messages (logs mostly)
au BufNewFile,BufRead */logs/couchdb/{,.log}{,.[0-9]*,-[0-9]*} setf couch_log
au BufNewFile,BufRead */log/{auth,cron,daemon,debug,kern,lpr,mail,messages,news/news,syslog,user}{,.log,.err,.info,.warn,.crit,.notice}{,.[0-9]*,-[0-9]*} setf messages
```

The following file exists : `/usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/couch_log.vim`

When I open `~/logs/couchdb/test.log`, I am getting a `filetype=messages` instead of the expected `filetype=couch_log`.

What am I missing ?

Comment: What is the output of `:verbose set ft`?

Comment: Sorry was out of the office : 
 `filetype=messages
        Last set from ~/.vimrc`
So it looks like it's not looking in the file that I've set up...

Comment: even after deleting the .vimrc file it still does not work. Now there is no filetype at all

Comment: `set nocp` and `filetype plugin on` should have been in your vimrc

Comment: do not use `:setf`, but instead rather use `:set filetype=`

Comment: will give that a try. What is the reason for which the shortcut would not work ? All examples online use `setf`

Comment: do you use your own filetype (couch_log), not bundled with vim? (in my filetype.vim there is no such a row as you show in the post)

Comment: Yes it's my own filetype which I added into filetype.vim

Comment: Ah it's not enough to have the file in the syntax folder ? OK will add it and check that it works then.

Comment: @MaximKim actually nocp is not necessary if you have a vimrc.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble indeed, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a bug in your filename glob pattern. The one you showed:

```
*/logs/couchdb/{,.log}{,.[0-9]*,-[0-9]*}
```

It will indeed match files inside a `logs/couchdb/` directory, but the last part will only match files named `.log` or `.789` or `-789` or `.log.789` or `.log-789`. Yes, these are full filenames, only filenames starting with `.` or `-` are valid. If you want to match any files with a log extension, you need to use `*.log` instead. You can then add the second part to also include numbered log files.

So, for example, it seems to me this would work:

```
*/logs/couchdb/*.log{,.[0-9]*,-[0-9]*}
```

This would match `test.log` or `test.log.789` or `test.log-789`.

Or, you might want to just keep it simple and match on the directory name, match any filename, regardless of extension:

```
*/logs/couchdb/*
```

I can't really explain why you're getting a filetype of `messages` on that `test.log`, since that second pattern isn't really matching that filename either... So I can't really explain it. You might want to use `:verbose set filetype?` to understand where it's being set (it will list the rule where it's coming from, with the file and line, so you can easily find it.)

Assuming the pattern with the proper `*` wildcard for the filename solves your issue, there are a couple other things you might want to consider.

First, instead of modifying file `/usr/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim` of your Vim installation, create a new user-local file for your user instead.

Create a directory `~/.vim/ftdetect`. Inside it, create `~/.vim/ftdetect/couch_log.vim` with the single line:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead */logs/couchdb/*.log{,.[0-9]*,-[0-9]*} set filetype=couch_log
```

If you really want this configuration to be sustem-wide, you can do the same with a `ftdetect` directory under `$VIMRUNTIME` (probably somewhere under `/usr/share/vim` in your system, check `:echo $VIMRUNTIME` to find out exactly where.)

The main advantage of not modifying a system file is that you won't lose the setting if you upgrade or reinstall Vim on that machine, which would probably overwrite the file you modified. Also, by keeping it inside your `.vim`, it's easy to take that with you to a different machine, since you can transport all your configurations together from a single `~/.vim` directory.

You don't need to create an `augroup` for this rule, Vim does that automatically for you as it sources `*.vim` files from the `ftdetect` directory.

Finally, you'll probably want to use `set filetype=couch_log`, rather than `setf couch_log`, in your filetype detection override.

The reason for it is that `set filetype=couch_log` will always set the filetype unconditionally, even if the file name has already matched another pattern and has been assigned a filetype in a previous rule. `setf couch_log`, on the other hand, will only set the filetype if one wasn't set yet. So you might end up skipping the setting if the file previously matched another filename pattern and was assigned a filetype already.

Since you're writing your overrides, you'll probably want to always use the stronger `set filetype=...`, since you probably want your rule to "win" in case a file matches multiple rules.

See [`:help ftdetect`](https://vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#ftdetect), it has more details on Vim's handling of the `ftdetect` directory and also spells out the differences between `set filetype` and `setf`.

Comment: thank you very much that was it

Comment: Will also follow your advice re:creating my own directory etc. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Try the following minimal vimrc:

```
set nocompatible
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

For filetypes to be properly detected `filetype` should be on (`:h filetype`). By default it is off when vim is in `nocompatible` mode which might be the case here.

Not sure what was in your vimrc before you have deleted it, but it looks like `filetype=messages` was somehow set from it.

**PS**

I can't find that `couch_log.vim` in my distribution, so I suspect this is external thing and you want to detect a filetype and apply it.

Use the following in minimal vimrc:

```
set nocompatible
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

au BufNewFile,BufRead */logs/couchdb/{,.log}{,.[0-9]*,-[0-9]*} set ft=couch_log
```

NOTE: there is difference in command compared to your initial one: `set ft=couch_log` instead of `setf couch_log`.

Although proper way to do it is to follow what vim help states in `:h ftdetect`

```
                            *ftdetect*
   1. Create your user runtime directory.  You would normally use the first
      item of the 'runtimepath' option.  Then create the directory "ftdetect"
      inside it.  Example for Unix: >
    :!mkdir ~/.vim
    :!mkdir ~/.vim/ftdetect
<
   2. Create a file that contains an autocommand to detect the file type.
      Example: >
    au BufRead,BufNewFile *.mine        set filetype=mine
<     Note that there is no "augroup" command, this has already been done
      when sourcing your file.  You could also use the pattern "*" and then
      check the contents of the file to recognize it.
      Write this file as "mine.vim" in the "ftdetect" directory in your user
      runtime directory.  For example, for Unix: >
    :w ~/.vim/ftdetect/mine.vim

<  3. To use the new filetype detection you must restart Vim.
```

Comment: Thks for taking the time. I created a .vimrc file containing your recommendations but no luck. It still does not pick up the correct file type.

Comment: 1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim80/debian.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim80/indent.vim
  9: ~/.vimrc
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/nosyntax.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/gzip.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/logiPat.vim

Comment: 14: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/manpager.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/matchparen.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/spellfile.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 20: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tohtml.vim
 21: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 22: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 23: /usr/share/vim/vim80/scripts.vim

Comment: is the output of `:scriptnames`

Comment: Before I deleted the .vimrc it was just a line to assign the type `messages` to `.log` files

Comment: By "not pickup correct filetypes" do you mean it is still messages? With the minimal vimrc what is output of `:verbose set ft?` @Chapo

Comment: No it's empty now.

Comment: what is couch_log filetype? Is it smth you created? Then it shouldn't be in filetype.vim of your vim runtime. It should be in your `.vim/ftdetect` directory with `couch_log.vim` file where you should have that autocommand defined

Comment: or in your vimrc

Comment: Ah it's not enough to have the file in the syntax folder ? OK will add it and check that it works then.

Comment: You mean the au bufnewfile etc right?

Comment: @Chapo, yes, I have updated answer to reflect this

Comment: Syntax enable is better than on

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thx, good to know

Comment: Thanks for your help @MaximKim but in the end it was just that my regex was wrong and didn't pickup the right files...